# removeClass when last image in slider is active

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I use **easySlider plugin** to slide images, and what i want to achieve, if the last image is `active` the text *"highlight me"* change color to `red` I try it by my self but I have no luck of getting the correct answer, I setup [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/jhunlio/kKY5U/3/)

my current code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#slider > ul > li:last").addClass("selected");
          });
                if(".selected") {
                $("#selected").addClass("select");
            }

            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think I might be able to help. Modded your code a bit, let me know what you think: http://jsfiddle.net/kKY5U/5/

Basically, added listeners for the prev and next buttons

```
var imgCount = 0;
$("#nextBtn").click(function() {
    imgCount++;
    $("#select").removeClass("select")

    if (imgCount == picArray.length - 1) {
        $("#select").addClass("select")
    }
});

$("#prevBtn").click(function() {
    imgCount--;
    $("#select").removeClass("select")

    if (imgCount == 0) {
        $("#select").addClass("select")
    }
});
```

Also, changed up a little of your CSS, and make the h1 tags in styled span.

Comment: try your code i can figure out why my work is not working.. thanks for your helpful reply.. hope i can figure out what is wrong..